# Explicit formula for hermitian form on coadjoint orbit of $G$ on $\mathfrak{g}^*$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups, sg.symplectic-geometry, orbifolds

Let $G$ be a compact Lie group and $\mathfrak{g}$ be its Lie algebra and $\mathfrak{g}^*$ be its dual , then I am looking for explicit formula for hermitian form on coadjoint orbit of $G$ on $\mathfrak{g}^*$.(note that $h=g-i\omega$ and for $\omega$ we have Kirilov symplectic 2-form )(maybe it be possible by Hodge star , but i couldn't find)

Comment: There are Kahler and hyper-Kaehler metrics on orbits of real and complex semisimple Lie algebras, as far as I understand the explicit description is not known. Hyper-Kaehler metric contructed by Kronheimer and related to Nahm monopole equations.

Comment: Dear Alexander Chervov, can you write your email for me?

Comment: What about if we define the hermitian form as $h(X,Y)=-i\omega(X,\bar Y)=-i<F,[X,\bar Y]>$, but I am still looking for explicit description and maybe by Hodge star

Comment: Al.mylastname at gmail.com   Omega ( x y ) is anti symmetric is not it ?

Comment: Thanks for email. $\omega(X,\bar Y) $ is symplectic fors and the second equality is KKS symplectic form

Comment: As far as I remember formula is like $\omega(X, JY)$ where J is complex struture, but as far as I remember it might be not easy to introduce J on apriori real manifolds.

Comment: As far as I remember the main point is that we start with REAL group like SO(n), SU(n) and obtain a complex structure on its orbits.

Comment: I have posted a new question, maybe it be halpful for finding an explicit formula for hermitian form of coadjoint orbit http://mathoverflow.net/questions/154093/explicit-form-for-hermitian-structure-h-with-respect-to-omega